# jquery innerWidth / outerWidth and javascript clientWidth / offsetWidth gives wrong values on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have an HTML tag of `<a>` inside a `div`.
The div style uses 'Lato' font with font-weight of 700.

When I try to get the `a` tag width, I get wrong values in chrome.

I tried:

```
width()
outerWidth()
innerWidth()
clientWidth
offsetWidth
```

they all give me wrong values.

I also noticed that when I remove the font-weight css style, This problem disappears.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` is an inline element.  As such it doesn't use the box model.   Think of it as "slippery".  I'm not sure why it would work with a different font weight.

You probably want to measure the innerWidth of the first block-level parent of the `<a>`.

Something like:

```
$('<a>').closest('div').innerWidth();
```

Alternately, you could make it a block using css, then your existing js should work:

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```